# Operator as vs Enum.TryParse

Tags: c#

I have a general question. I have 2 cases (method Test1 and Test2, and I don't know what is the best approach (Performance, ignore case, all aspects):

```
    public void Test1(object transcodingStatus)
    {
        string _transcodingStatus = transcodingStatus as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_transcodingStatus))
        {
            if (_transcodingStatus.ToUpper() == AWSTranscoderStatusBindingModel.COMPLETED.ToString())
            {
                //DO LOGIC
            }
        }
    }

    public void Test2(object transcodingStatus)
    {
        if (transcodingStatus != null)
        {
            AWSTranscoderStatusBindingModel enumVale = AWSTranscoderStatusBindingModel.COMPLETED;
            if (Enum.TryParse(transcodingStatus.ToString(), false, out enumVale))
            {
                if (enumVale == AWSTranscoderStatusBindingModel.COMPLETED)
                {
                    //DO LOGIC
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to all helpers :)

Comment: I'm curious why the parameter is type `object` to begin with. Why is it not `AWSTranscoderStatusBindingModel?` or `string`?

Comment: The second, undoubtedly. A)  because first one does case insensitive comparison wrongly. B) because when there is an existing method is almost always better to use it. Performance? I guess you do not have a MEASURED issue here

Comment: If you can avoid parsing enums from string altogether it will even faster. Serializers typically give the abilty to serialize enums as integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enum.TryParse is more efficient than other things in this case